# Why this css selector is not working properly?

Tags: css-selectors, python-requests-html

While  Extracting 1st Company's name using css selectors output is perfect But Second selector **"sel2"** returns None

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

page=session.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/indcomp.php")

#print(page)

sel1 = '#mc_content > section > section > div.clearfix.stat_container > div.columnst.FR.wbg.brdwht > div > div.bsr_table.hist_tbl_hm.PR.Ohidden > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.PR > span.gld13.disin'
sel2 = '#mc_content > section > section > div.clearfix.stat_container > div.columnst.FR.wbg.brdwht > div > div.bsr_table.hist_tbl_hm.PR.Ohidden > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.PR > span.gld13.disin'

temp=page.html.find(sel1, first=True).text
print(temp.strip("\n Add to \n Watchlist | Portfolio"))

temp=page.html.find(sel2, first=True).text
print(temp.strip("\n Add to \n Watchlist | Portfolio"))
```

**Output Needed** 
Carborundum 
Grindwell Norto

 For More refernece and choosing selectors:-
[image]

https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/indcomp.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of this particular page, you can use much simpler selectors:

```
sel1 = 'span > a'
temp=page.html.find(sel1)
print(temp[0].text)
print(temp[1].text)
```

Output:

```
Carborundum
Grindwell Norto
```

Comment: Can you explain How did u figured out.Thanks @Jack Fleeting for solving these.

Comment: I am unable to even get high low prices by following selector:- 

'#mc_content > section > section > div.clearfix.stat_container > div.columnst.FR.wbg.brdwht > div > div.bsr_table.hist_tbl_hm.PR.Ohidden > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)'



Please even solve it too.

Comment: I looked at the page source for that. As to you other targets - this page's html is really complicated; instead of trying to do it manually with css selectors, I would just load the whole table into pandas and then use standard pandas methods to extract the targets. Much simpler: `pd.read_html(page.text)`.

Comment: Can U suggest me resources to learn scrapping through **Pandas** @jack

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI - Start with something like this: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/web-scraping-with-pandas-and-beautifulsoup/